# Add Email Functionality to Custom Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, email

I'm creating a custom LWC component and would like to add email functionality similar to the native experience within Salesforce, for example on the Activity component within a contact.

For example, this is the email tab I'm referring to, which i can find on a contact within my Salesforce instance.

[image]

Is there a way to add the above Email tab component to my custom LWC component? Or, is it possible to add the entire Activity component (which houses the Email tab shown above) within my custom LWC?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Updated my question to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can search the component library for all the reusable components. These two are not part of that library

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components

What you'll need to do is

- Query the **Feed** object and re-create the activity component
- Create a custom UI to send emails similar to Salesforce and use SingleEmail in Apex to send the emails